# What is significance of params in html?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to connect dots for a website code and stuck at this place.Can somebody pls explain what does this means in `html`, `knockoutJS` ?What is `params` used for and what is `route` here ?

```
<x-header params="route: route"></x-header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A KnockoutJS `component` is registered (somewhere else) with the name `x-header`. When we want to use the `x-header` component, it uses the same syntax as a html tag, hence the mix up.

The `params`attribute is passing the `value` of a separate object named `route` (the right side of the colon). It just so happens that the name that it will be passed as will also be `route` (left side of the colon).

This params value is being passed to the `x-header` component's viewModel. It may looks something like this:

```
    function viewModelXHeader(params)
    {
       var self = this;
       self.route = params.route;
       <other stuff that uses self.route>
    }
```

The `params` attribute can be passed any number of parameters with a comma delimiter, and they are then available within the viewModel:

```
<x-header params="route: route, firstname: firstname, title: 'hello world'"></x-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing in HTML. Somewhere in the code you'll find that a Knockout component has been defined which uses `x-header` as its tag name. The `params` attribute is just where the author of that component decided the parameters for it would be.